# Coldfusion regex to replace new Instagram code with old one

Tags: regex, coldfusion, instagram

I have a ColdFusion blog where people can insert embedded Tweets and Instagram codes. The new Instagram embed codes are hideous and causes tons of extra lines if there are multiple Instagram embed codes.

I've been trying to come up with a regex in ColdFusion that would convert the new code, i.e. this:

```
<blockquote class="instagram-media" data-instgrm-captioned data-instgrm-version="4" style=" background:#FFF; border:0; border-radius:3px; box-shadow:0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15); margin: 1px; max-width:658px; padding:0; width:99.375%; width:-webkit-calc(100% - 2px); width:calc(100% - 2px);"><div style="padding:8px;"> <div style=" background:#F8F8F8; line-height:0; margin-top:40px; padding:50% 0; text-align:center; width:100%;"> <div style=" background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACwAAAAsCAMAAAApWqozAAAAGFBMVEUiIiI9PT0eHh4gIB4hIBkcHBwcHBwcHBydr+JQAAAACHRSTlMABA4YHyQsM5jtaMwAAADfSURBVDjL7ZVBEgMhCAQBAf//42xcNbpAqakcM0ftUmFAAIBE81IqBJdS3lS6zs3bIpB9WED3YYXFPmHRfT8sgyrCP1x8uEUxLMzNWElFOYCV6mHWWwMzdPEKHlhLw7NWJqkHc4uIZphavDzA2JPzUDsBZziNae2S6owH8xPmX8G7zzgKEOPUoYHvGz1TBCxMkd3kwNVbU0gKHkx+iZILf77IofhrY1nYFnB/lQPb79drWOyJVa/DAvg9B/rLB4cC+Nqgdz/TvBbBnr6GBReqn/nRmDgaQEej7WhonozjF+Y2I/fZou/qAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); display:block; height:44px; margin:0 auto -44px; position:relative; top:-22px; width:44px;"></div></div> <p style=" margin:8px 0 0 0; padding:0 4px;"> <a href="https://instagram.com/p/ugWQkzgF9R/" style=" color:#000; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; line-height:17px; text-decoration:none; word-wrap:break-word;" target="_top">&#39;Making this album, we went back and listened to all the music that had brought us into ourselves, then we said, &#39;Now let&#39;s misremember it.&#39; U2 Take On The World. Cover Story, Rolling Stone.</a></p> <p style=" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:8px; overflow:hidden; padding:8px 0 7px; text-align:center; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap;">Una foto publicada por U2 Official (@u2) el <time style=" font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px;" datetime="2014-10-23T18:41:21+00:00">Oct 10, 2014 at 11:41 PDT</time></p></div></blockquote>
<script async defer src="//platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js"></script>
```

Into the old code, i.e. this:

```
<iframe src="http://instagram.com/p/ugWQkzgF9R/embed/" width="612" height="692" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

I've had no luck, especially if there are more than one embedded Instagram photos in the article. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You do realize that the embed code is individual for every image (it contains image caption and date), so that you can't simply do a search-and-replace operation? Also, the `http://instagram.com/p/ugWQkzgF9R/embed/` still seems to work, why change it?

Comment: That being said, you should consider using their [OEmbed endpoint (scroll down)](http://instagram.com/developer/embedding/) instead of painfully swapping in truly ugly HTML into your blog source code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a regular expression you need, demonstrated in Python:

```
ss = '<blockquote class="instagram-media" data-instgrm-captioned data-instgrm-version="4" style=" background:#FFF; border:0; border-radius:3px; box-shadow:0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15); margin: 1px; max-width:658px; padding:0; width:99.375%; width:-webkit-calc(100% - 2px); width:calc(100% - 2px);"><div style="padding:8px;"> <div style=" background:#F8F8F8; line-height:0; margin-top:40px; padding:50% 0; text-align:center; width:100%;"> <div style=" background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACwAAAAsCAMAAAApWqozAAAAGFBMVEUiIiI9PT0eHh4gIB4hIBkcHBwcHBwcHBydr+JQAAAACHRSTlMABA4YHyQsM5jtaMwAAADfSURBVDjL7ZVBEgMhCAQBAf//42xcNbpAqakcM0ftUmFAAIBE81IqBJdS3lS6zs3bIpB9WED3YYXFPmHRfT8sgyrCP1x8uEUxLMzNWElFOYCV6mHWWwMzdPEKHlhLw7NWJqkHc4uIZphavDzA2JPzUDsBZziNae2S6owH8xPmX8G7zzgKEOPUoYHvGz1TBCxMkd3kwNVbU0gKHkx+iZILf77IofhrY1nYFnB/lQPb79drWOyJVa/DAvg9B/rLB4cC+Nqgdz/TvBbBnr6GBReqn/nRmDgaQEej7WhonozjF+Y2I/fZou/qAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); display:block; height:44px; margin:0 auto -44px; position:relative; top:-22px; width:44px;"></div></div> <p style=" margin:8px 0 0 0; padding:0 4px;"> <a href="https://instagram.com/p/ugWQkzgF9R/" style=" color:#000; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; line-height:17px; text-decoration:none; word-wrap:break-word;" target="_top">&#39;Making this album, we went back and listened to all the music that had brought us into ourselves, then we said, &#39;Now let&#39;s misremember it.&#39; U2 Take On The World. Cover Story, Rolling Stone.</a></p> <p style=" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:8px; overflow:hidden; padding:8px 0 7px; text-align:center; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap;">Una foto publicada por U2 Official (@u2) el <time style=" font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px;" datetime="2014-10-23T18:41:21+00:00">Oct 10, 2014 at 11:41 PDT</time></p></div></blockquote>'

p = re.findall(r'instagram\.com/p/(\w*)/',ss) # This is the actual regex you were looking for

print '<iframe src="http://instagram.com/p/' + p[0] + '/embed/" width="612" height="692" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>'
```

Let me know if you need any help.